# how to write .js file to read from xml file

Tags: javascript, xml

I went through the example but my xml file is somewhat different from the file used in example
My xml file looks like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>

<lst name="responseHeader">
  <int name="status">0</int>
  <int name="QTime">3</int>
  <lst name="params">
    <str name="facet">on</str>
    <str name="indent">on</str>
    <str name="start">0</str>
    <str name="q">*:*</str>
    <str name="facet.field">ISS_RATE_TXT</str>
    <str name="rows">10</str>
    <str name="version">2.2</str>
  </lst>
</lst>
<result name="response" numFound="2627" start="0">
  <doc>
    <str name="ASSET_CLASS_MNEM">OTHER     </str>
    <str name="ISS_RATE_TXT">OTH ASSETS</str>
    <str name="RCD_ID">4127      </str>
    <str name="RCD_NUM">1</str>
  </doc>
  <doc>
    <str name="ASSET_CLASS_MNEM">EQUITY    </str>
    <str name="ISS_RATE_TXT">INTL OIL</str>
    <str name="RCD_ID">4142      </str>
    <str name="RCD_NUM">2</str>
  </doc>
  <doc>
    <str name="ASSET_CLASS_MNEM">BALANCE   </str>
    <str name="ISS_RATE_TXT">CASH</str>
    <str name="RCD_ID">4145      </str>
    <str name="RCD_NUM">3</str>
  </doc>
  <doc>
    <str name="ASSET_CLASS_MNEM">REC/PAY   </str>
    <str name="ISS_RATE_TXT">CASH</str>
    <str name="RCD_ID">4149      </str>
    <str name="RCD_NUM">4</str>
  </doc>
  <doc>
    <str name="ASSET_CLASS_MNEM">BALANCE   </str>
    <str name="ISS_RATE_TXT">CASH</str>
    <str name="RCD_ID">4146      </str>
    <str name="RCD_NUM">5</str>
  </doc>
  <doc>
    <str name="ASSET_CLASS_MNEM">REC/PAY   </str>
    <str name="ISS_RATE_TXT">CASH</str>
    <str name="RCD_ID">4148      </str>
    <str name="RCD_NUM">6</str>
  </doc>
  <doc>
    <str name="ASSET_CLASS_MNEM">EQUITY    </str>
    <str name="ISS_RATE_TXT">EQ FUNDS</str>
    <str name="RCD_ID">4143      </str>
    <str name="RCD_NUM">7</str>
  </doc>
  <doc>
    <str name="ASSET_CLASS_MNEM">EQUITY    </str>
    <str name="ISS_RATE_TXT">EQ FUNDS</str>
    <str name="RCD_ID">4144      </str>
    <str name="RCD_NUM">8</str>
  </doc>
  <doc>
    <str name="ASSET_CLASS_MNEM">EQUITY    </str>
    <str name="ISS_RATE_TXT">PUB/BRD</str>
    <str name="RCD_ID">4135      </str>
    <str name="RCD_NUM">9</str>
  </doc>
  <doc>
    <str name="ASSET_CLASS_MNEM">EQUITY    </str>
    <str name="ISS_RATE_TXT">OTH FIN</str>
    <str name="RCD_ID">4134      </str>
    <str name="RCD_NUM">10</str>
  </doc>
</result>
</response>
```

Could someone please tell how to modify the xml-grid.js file in the example

Comment: What xml-grid.js file???

Comment: Which example? Which *xml-grid.js* file?

Comment: Are you using regular javascript or do you also use third party library such as jQuery, mootools, prototype etc.? The latter makes requesting for xml files easier.

Answer (score 0):

First of all; to request the XML file it needs to be in the same web server as your javascript file (or else the browser will fail to load the XML file).

To load the XML file to javascript you need to use the [XMLHttpRequest object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/xmlhttprequest), though if you want support in IE5 and IE6 you need to do some ActiveX control magic. Here is an example of how to do it with XMLHttpRequest:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  // create the request object

request.open('GET', '/xml-grid.js', false);
  // open http session to the file

request.send(null);
  // Send the request (with nothing)

if (request.status == 200) {
  // if request was okay

    console.log(request.responseText);
      // write to console the response in text

}
```